# Need superuser right on linux folder and subfolders

Tags: linux, permissions, rights

Trick question here :

I need to have a user with all rights on files an folders in a particular directory and sub directories.

It cannot be root and cannot have sudo access.

The subforlders have 0750 rights and the owners and groups are each different and it cannot be changed.

Is there a way to do it without chroot, jailkit or others things like that?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could do this with ACLs...

Comment: I see that it could be a solution, I'll check with the system administrators if they are able to implement it! Thanks.